# Datasheet View to include overlay data

Tags: calendar, datasheet

Is there a way to include the data from the calendar overlays in the datasheet view? I am trying to aggregate the data from the different calendars into a table or datasheet format.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible out of the box, but you can code the data requests you need and the presentation you need. I'll mark this answer community wiki so anyone can improve and add details as needed.